# range of numeric values with unit in Solr

Tags: solr, range, numeric, unit-conversion

My problem is that i have documents containing a numeric value and a unit like this:

weight:100g

weight:1000kg

And i want to make querys like this:

weight:[5g TO 100KG]

Of course this doent work as easy as it sounds, the values are saved as strings. I did some research and came up with this https://dzone.com/articles/build-a-custom-solr-filter-to-handle-unit-conversions.

This worked out pretty well, i can search for:
weight:100000g and get results containing weight:100kg, nice. But i cant figure out how to extend this, to make a range-search possible.

Thanks for help, Patrick

Comment: Is indexing the unit separately not an option?

Comment: An option could be to have something like this:
weight:[100, "kg"]
Could this help?